# Small fonts when using LaTeX in Anki

Tags: latex, anki

I'm trying to make some flashcards in Anki using latex. I can create the cards and everything but when I visualize them inside Anki (Linux version), the fonts look tiny and there is a lot of white space. That would be a minor thing if the cards looked fine in [ankiweb](https://ankiweb.net/) and smartphones...but they don't look pretty there either: the fonts are readable, but still small and ugly (I take it that Anki turns the latex into an image, so that could be the problem).

My header in the *notetype* is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage{manki}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\begin{document}
```

Does that look fine? Any clue? I also tried adding `\Huge` after `\begin{document}`, but it didn't help.

BTW, but I'm using [LaTeX Note Importer](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1199027445), which is pretty cool and allows you to import notes stored in a tex file...but this is probably not important since the imported cards look fine.

Cheers.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395929 could help

Comment: I tried the approach in [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Anki/comments/daxj0z/how_to_get_anki_working_with_tikz_package_for/) and so far so good. Not tried the one in the link above yet, but it looks similar (pdflatex-based). I'll give it a try when/if I run intro troubles :) Thanks!!